# codeigniter and tank auth error

Tags: php, codeigniter, tankauth

Hi I am having trouble with my log in for my user menu. I am trying to get it so on the right side. When user is_logged_in can see there user name and the log out and on the left side still display the home, forum, and contact. But for some reason when user is logged in still displays the register and sign in links. How do I fix it I am using Tank_Auth and Codeigniter

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
<div class="container">
<div class="navbar-header">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
</button>
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#"></a>
</div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<?php if ($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') != 1): ?>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
<li class="active"><a href="<?php echo base_url();?>">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Forum</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
<?php if ($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') != 0): ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url('auth/register');?>">Register</a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url('auth/login');?>">Sign In</a></li>
</ul>
<?php else: ?>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

<li class="active"><a href=""><strong><?php echo $username; ?></strong></a></li>
<li><a href="<?php echo base_url('/auth/logout/'); ?>">Log Out</a></li>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>
</div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

place `<?php endif; ?>` after second ul like below

```
<?php if ($this->session->userdata('is_logged_in') != 0): ?>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('auth/register');?>">Register</a></li>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url('auth/login');?>">Sign In</a></li>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

you are using Tank_Auth so you should use blow code to check user logged in

`$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()`

Comment: Did not work now displaying error line 48 which is the closing div of menu.

Comment: please place the `endif` after sign in ul like in updated answer. please check

Comment: I have edited the part up top show you what I have done still nothing.

Comment: you are using tank_auth so use this `$this->tank_auth->is_logged_in()`